# TypeError: must be str, not datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, datetime

here is my code it works fine for the first print and the give me this error 
TypeError: must be str, not datetime.timedelta

```
import datetime
hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour
tomorrow = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(50):
    hour += 1
    print(hour)
    if hour >= 23:
        tomorrow = tomorrow + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        tomorrow = tomorrow.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        hour = 9
        print (tomorrow)
```

here is the output :

```
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
07/12/2017
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hamza.salhi\Desktop\datetime test.py", line 8, in <module>
    tomorrow = tomorrow + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
TypeError: must be str, not datetime.timedelta
```

please can someone tell me why it works fine at first then i get that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the first time because `tomorrow` is a `datetime.datetime` instance then:

```
tomorrow = datetime.datetime.now()
```

However, after that first time, you *replace `tomorrow` with a string*:

```
tomorrow = tomorrow.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

You can't add a `timedelta()` object to a string. Don't rebind `tomorrow`. Either assign the string to a different name, or only format the object for printing (and not assign it to a name at all):

```
if hour >= 23:
    tomorrow = tomorrow + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    tomorrow_formatted = tomorrow.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    hour = 9
    print(tomorrow_formatted)  # different name
    print(tomorrow.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))  # print the `strftime()` result
```

Comment: I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer, to deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answer!

Answer (score 0):

`tomorrow = tomorrow.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` 
Changes the type of tomorrow to string, so it can't be added to datetime.timedelta.

Instead of doing:

```
tomorrow = tomorrow + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow = tomorrow.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
...
print (tomorrow)
```

Try:

```
tomorrow = tomorrow + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
...
print('{:%d/%m/%Y}'.format(tomorrow))
```